# creating a gradient bar ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

How would I create a gradient bar so that when I pan over it I could change the color?

I could easily add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and get some translation within a `UIView`, but how would I change the RGB values of a `UIColor` appropriately?

[image]

Comment: If you are asking how to create a gradient background then you should probably just create an image and use it as the background.

Comment: @cabellicar123 edited my question, that's not what I'm asking. Thanks

Comment: @Apollo remember to accept an answer if it is correct.

Comment: @Fogmeister bro chill

Comment: I'm just checking that you saw the answers. Too many people just leave the answers hanging. In this case it wasn't even my answer. just trying to be helpful.

Comment: @Fogmeister understandable. Nice blog btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an RGB colour, I would use HSB. Just change the hue depending on the swipe.

If you treat the top of the screen as 0.0 and the bottom as 1.0, as the user swipes their finger from top to bottom, the colour should go through it's full spectrum. Then

```
CGFloat percentTranslation = currentY / self.view.bounds.size.height;
[UIColor colorWithHue:percentTranslation saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0]
```

Comment: perhaps you could elaborate on what you mean by percentTranslation? Thanks!

Comment: Percent translation is the percentage down the bar you are. Top of the bar is 1.0. Bottom of the bar is 0.0.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before. The easiest way without doubt is to create a png image and use that.

You can calculate the per pixel colour but it's far quicker to just use an image.

In fact. I created a full colour picker which you can see in my app https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/game-of-life/id477039315?mt=8

The colour bar in the 2nd screen shot is just a png. And the colour square uses a transparent image that has a black-transparent gradient bottom to top and a white-transparent gradient left to right.

All I do is set the background colour of the image view when the colour is selected on the bar.